# How to disable lenses in the Dash menu?

Tags: unity-dash, menu, lenses

How can I disable some lenses in the Dash menu?

Comment: Open terminal: sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping

Answer (score 26):

There are several ways to do this, though one would think the easiest thing for ubuntu to do would be to have some easy to access configuration options from within the dash, but that's just crazy talk.

*If you're confident using the terminal then I recommend option 1, because the behaviour of the software center will be misleading and confusing.*

#### Option 1 - Use the Terminal (Recommended)

1. Open the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. To check what scopes and lenses are currently installed, use `dpkg` with `grep`. e.g. list all scopes and lens packages

   ```
   $ dpkg -l | egrep "(unity-lens-|unity-scope-)"
   ii  unity-lens-applications     ...     Application lens for unity
   ii  unity-lens-files            ...     File lens for unity
   ii  unity-lens-gwibber          ...     Gwibber Lens for unity
   ii  unity-lens-photos           ...     Unity Photos Lens
   ii  unity-lens-shopping         ...     Shopping lens for unity
   ```

   **Notes on 14.04**

   14.04 has a great many more lenses and scopes than ever before. Some of which *can't* removed without destroying the system e.g. `unity-scope-home`.

   These are some of the scopes and lenses installed by default in 14.04:

   ```
   unity-lens-video
   unity-lens-friends
   unity-scope-audacious 
   unity-scope-calculator 
   unity-scope-chromiumbookmarks 
   unity-scope-clementine 
   unity-scope-colourlovers 
   unity-scope-devhelp 
   unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks 
   unity-scope-gdrive 
   unity-scope-gmusicbrowser 
   unity-scope-gourmet 
   unity-scope-guayadeque 
   unity-scope-home 
   unity-scope-manpages 
   unity-scope-musicstores 
   unity-scope-musique 
   unity-scope-openclipart 
   unity-scope-texdoc 
   unity-scope-tomboy 
   unity-scope-video-remote 
   unity-scope-virtualbox 
   unity-scope-yelp 
   unity-scope-zotero
   ```

   Scopes and leneses after most of the one's that can be removed have been removed:

   ```
   $ dpkg -l | egrep "(unity-lens-|unity-scope-)"
   ii  unity-lens-applications ... Application lens for unity
   ii  unity-lens-files        ... File lens for unity
   ii  unity-scope-home        ... Home scope that aggregates results from multiple scopes
   ```

   - [What do the various dpkg flags like 'ii' 'rc' mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean)
3. To remove a lens use `apt-get remove`. e.g. remove the unity shopping lens:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge unity-lens-shopping
   ```

#### Option 2 - Use Ubuntu Software Center

1. Open up Software Center and search for "lens".
2. Uninstall by selecting the item and clicking "Remove".

   **IMPORTANT!**

   - You must select *Show (count) technical items* to show all installed lenses. e.g. The "shopping lens" is a technical item, which personally I think is a little bit cheeky. You know, because you're too dumb to know what that is.
   - Don't select "Installed" and then search for "lens". This doesn't do what you might expect. It *should* list any "installed" len's, however it doesn't do that. Probably a bug.

#### What lenses do I recommend uninstalling?

All of them except for `unity-lens-applications` and possibly `unity-lens-files`. Personally I'd be <strike>happy</strike> a great deal happier without the dash. In place of which was a simple, straight forward, no messing, fast-as-possible, application launcher. I can't belive I'm about to say this, but there's actually something I miss about windows.

**Note on 14.04** You can't remove `unity-scope-home`  without remove the `unity-desktop` and breaking the entire system.

#### Additional Information

- [I have permanent connections to Canonical servers, what are they for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135602/i-have-permanent-connections-to-canonical-servers-what-are-they-for/145384#145384)

Comment: I agree. When I first started using Ubuntu, what I loved about it was its simplicity and speed. And If I'm not mistaken Unity is made to provide a straight forward environment in which can get your work done. I think Unity is moving away from its goals. I love the fact that I have a lot of options, but I wouldn't want to sacrifice speed or simplicity in return. I really disliked the "internal error detected" popups in Precise(isn't that one of the reasons people don't like Windows??). And the new ads on Quantal, with terms of service, I don't like this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on **14.04 Trusty**. I have uninstalled all lenses except for `unity-lens-applications` but they still show up in the dash. Any ideas?

Comment: @nifr Disabling it using the `unity-tweak-tool` still works: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107701/how-to-disable-lenses-in-the-in-the-dash-menu/375953#375953

Comment: @nifr Whar still shows up the dash? There are many more scopes and lenses in 14.04 than what I've described above. What does `dpkg -l | egrep "(lens|scope)"` show? e.g. you can't uninstall the  "home" scope i.e. `unity-scope-home` without uninstalling `unity-desktop`. Also, when removing the one's that you *can* uninstall, purge `apt-get remove --purge <package_name_here>`

Comment: @nifr I've updated the answer with some notes on 14.04.

Comment: Thanks for the update :) Sadly it's not possible to disable i.e. the shopping lens by just uninstalling a simple package anymore in 14.04.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Ubuntu 13.04 or newer:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

In the tweak tool you can use the search tab to modify the relevant settings:

- Uncheck "Search online sources"
- Uncheck "Show more suggestions"
- Uncheck "Enable search of your files"

Answer (score 6):

Uninstalling the lenses does not work in 14.04.

What works is:

- install dconf-editor
- remove scopes from the strings in `com -> canonical -> unity -> dash`. I left only `home.scope` in there.
- logout, login, enjoy.

(From [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/372015/4246))

---

You can also do it without installing dconf-editor. Edit the string with double quotes to your liking:

```
$ dconf write /com/canonical/unity/dash/scopes "['home.scope', 'applications.scope', 'files.scope']"
```

(From [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/419620/4246))

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](https://launchpad.net/~aking1012-com/+archive/lenstoggle) a small package I whipped up if you're comfortable with either setsid unity or logging out

Comment: Great tool. Unfortunately I have not found a way to disable the cities scope within the utilities scope as it often crashes on my system (Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64), but the calculator scope is very useful and I want to keep it.

Comment: It doesn't manipulate scopes directly...just lenses

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you know a way to manipulate scopes?

Comment: If you wanted to do that, you'ld have to modify all the lense descriptions or hijack the dbus calls depending on exactly what you wanted to do.  If you want to chat about it...pop in to the chat room

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and offer. But this would take up more time and efforts than I would spend on this issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 14.04LTS

1. Press *Super-A* to bring up the *Applications Scope*
2. Scroll until you see the *Dash Plugins* Header
3. If not already clicked, click the *Show more results* button
4. For each plugin you'd like to disable, click it, then click *disable*

I prefer this method because it doesn't require super-user privileges, thus, it is less likely to break anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would imaging that the easiest way of doing this would be to uninstall it, logout and login. It would still be in the cache if you would like to install it again later on.

If you on the other hand do not want to uninstall it and want to just make it go away from the Dash you could just move it out of the `/usr/share/unity/lenses` folder.

For example let us say you have install the Askubuntu Lense like me.

you would then have a folder inside `/usr/share/unity/lenses` called **extras-unity-lens-askubuntu/**. Move that folder somewhere else. Logout. Login.

An example:

`cd /usr/share/unity/lenses`
`sudo mv extras-unity-lens-askubuntu/ ..`

This would move the askubuntu lense from the lense folder to the parent folder. If you logout/login, the askubuntu lense will be gone.

UPDATE - As aking1012 points out, typing `setsid unity` will "refresh" Unity with the changes.

Comment: just a note, if you `setsid unity`, you don't have to log out

Comment: `setsid unity` doesn't work for me. All windows decoration disappeared and the program didn't exit. It force me to `Ctrl+C` and `gnome-session-quit` to logout.

Comment: @BornToCode I would guess a bug or misconfiguration. Last time I tested this was a year ago. Maybe you can provide more information about yout system.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 13.04, last updated about less than a month ago. I think this go out of the topic, and I'll be kicked if the discussion go further :D.

Comment: `setsid unity` removes all window decorations and doesn't exit on **14.04**, too. Any suggestions how to debug this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Just open the terminal and exec this (without sudo):

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "['more_suggestions-amazon.scope', 'more_suggestions-u1ms.scope', 'more_suggestions-populartracks.scope', 'music-musicstore.scope', 'more_suggestions-ebay.scope', 'more_suggestions-ubuntushop.scope', 'more_suggestions-skimlinks.scope']"
```