# Is there a tool to manage dash lenses?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

My Ubuntu 12.04 dash has become a clutter on lenses. At first I installed every lens I found on the internet. Most of them now I seldom use. So, is there any quick way to add/hide/remove lenses?

Comment: Search them in USC and remove them?

Comment: i was looking something like hide-remove-changeposition etc..

Comment: [Partial answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/128295/12864). Good question though, and maybe something to file as a feature request.

Comment: Also relevant: https://lists.launchpad.net/unity-design/msg09969.html ... maybe if I implement more features into a half baked tool and it's received well, they'll ---reimplement it--- make a similar official tool :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lens Toggler has appeared, it can be installed using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aking1012-com/lenstoggle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-lenstoggler`
```

This is the thing I was asking for:

[image: Lens Toggle Interface]

Comment: It'd be great if the tool could also sort them. Even better if it could allow you to modify the Ctrl+tab shortcut (for switching lenses) and add shortcut to open a particular lens.

Comment: apparently it does not work in raring, as no repo is available for that. In software repository for aking1012 change distribution to precise

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't any such Lens manager yet in Ubuntu (24 September, 2012). But some apps are really in their way to appear soon. Such as [this lens toogler](https://launchpad.net/~aking1012-com/+archive/lenstoggle) app. Though this app is in PPA, you can use it.

We hope some more this kind of apps will appear in future and obviously in the standard repository.

Comment: "But some apps are really in their way to appear soon." Such as?

Comment: [this one](https://launchpad.net/~aking1012-com/+archive/lenstoggle)?

Comment: Would have been better if you added it to your answer :)