# How to configure which lenses appear in the Dash home screen?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

I have about 8 lenses installed.  Some of them (Everpad, AskUbuntu) I'd like to appear on the Dash home page, and others (Downloads) that are on the home page I would like to not be there.  Anyway to configure this?

Comment: Better answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/107701/how-to-disable-lenses-in-the-in-the-dash-menu

Answer (score 2):

Here's just what you need:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/lens-toggle-quickly-enable-disable.html

Comment: Nice tool...thanks, but it won't let me add/delete them from home screen in Dash, just enable/disable them altogether.  Still helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use dconf-editor ?

[image]

[image]

removing the files lens and adding the others should help a little bit but sill will load at the bottom, you would have to open the source for unity and change shell/dash/LensView.cpp

Comment: I think this controls the order of the lenses at the bottom of the screen.  Oddly enough, the contents of dconf-editor (applications, files, music) don't even match what my Dash is showing... Dunno whats up.