# Reclaim Super+M from Dash "music menu"

Tags: 16.04, unity, unity-dash

I want to map the Super+M keyboard shortcut to something, but it's globally assigned to open the dash music lens.

I checked in CCSM and Keyboard shortcuts system settings and while some Launcher and Dash related settings appear there I don't find the specific lens shortcut keys there.

Comment: I think if you disable the lens entirely, the keyboard shortcut becomes unmapped.

Comment: @wjandrea - is that possible?

Comment: See [How to disable lenses in the Dash menu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/107701/301745) This lens I think is called `unity-lens-music`.