# After  force-installing a 32-bit deb failed, how can I install the 64-bit version?

Tags: apt, dpkg, synaptic, google-earth

I tried to `dpkg -i --force-architecture google-earth-stable_i386.deb` and it failed.

But now when I try to install the amd64.deb it fails saying

> dpkg: error processing google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb
>   (--install):  google-earth-stable: 6.2.2.6613-r0 (Multi-Arch: no) is
>   not co-installable with google-earth-stable:i386 6.2.2.6613-r0
>   (Multi-Arch: no) which is currently installed Errors were encountered
>   while processing:  google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb

somehow it thinks the i386 version is installed. No google-earth files or directories even exist.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

outputs:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
>   google-earth-stable:i386:  google-earth-stable:i386 depends on
>   lsb-core (>= 3.2). dpkg: error processing google-earth-stable:i386
>   (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were
>   encountered while processing:  google-earth-stable:i386

so it does exist in some capacity.

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

does nothing out of the ordinary:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove
>   and 10 not upgraded.

The weird thing is that synaptic doesn't show any google earth package available let alone installed, nothing under the broken filter either.

I have also tried `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`

So, **my question**: How can I get rid of this issue?

Comment: seems things like this are happening pretty often recently, hoping for a lot of fixes in 12.10. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Couldn't install doesn't mean `dpkg` didn't try and give up half-way

There's nothing complicated about it. Observe this re-enactment:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-earth-stable:i386

$ dpkg --list | grep google-earth
iU  google-earth-stable:i386               6.0.3.2197-r0
```

The **`iU`** tells you that you wanted this package **i**-nstalled, but `dpkg` couldn't configure it, so it was leaving it **U**-nconfigured, *waiting for you to fix it.* The error you got `dpkg: error processing google-earth-stable:i386 (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured` tells you as much in simpler language.

#### `dpkg` must be explicitly told to remove a failed install

Just tell `dpkg` to not bother and remove the package:

`sudo dpkg --remove google-earth-stable:i386`

And then try installing the 64-bit package again.

#### Synaptic and `apt-get` don't care about one-off debs

You got nothing out of Synaptic or `apt-get` because they aren't aware of your problem. They concern themselves primarily with packages available in the repositories, which you manage *through them*. They are higher level tools which use `dpkg` under the hood, but don't care about any problems you create with `dpkg` unless it concerns them. If you tried to install any package, or Google Earth 64-bit if it was in some repository, with Synaptic or `apt-get`, they would definitely have whined about it.

#### Other helpful references

- The `.deb` file name and package name are usually different. You need the package name to do any operations with `dpkg`. Use `dpkg --list | grep xxxxx` where xxxxx is a small part of the file name sure to be in there, like `google` or `earth`.
- See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/18807/58612) for a great explanation of all the two-letter `dpkg` status flags.

Comment: beautiful! Thank you. Complicated for me. I never knew how to get the iU list via `dpkg --list`. Thanks again. Very helpful and simple once explained.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. `dpkg --list` is also useful to get the package name you need to be able to remove, etc. -- the deb file name won't help you at that point :)