# dpkg --get-selections shows packages marked "deinstall"

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

Executing `dpkg --get-selections` shows packages with one of the markers `install` or `deinstall`.

Some packages I could remove completely with `apt-get remove`.

1. What does `deinstall` mean?
2. What can be done so that the packages marked `deinstall` are not listed by `dpkg --get-selections` anymore?

Answer (score 25):

> What does "deinstall" mean?

From the [manpage of `dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dpkg.1.html) this means

> > the package is selected for  de-installation or removal (i.e.  we  want  to remove all files, except configuration files).

You also asked

> What can be done so that the packages marked "deinstall" are not listed by "dpkg --get-selections" anymore?

There are two ways you can do for not to be listed in the `dpkg --get-selections` command.

#### 1. Unselect the packages for removal

You can unselect the packages, which are selected for removal. In this way, `dpkg --get-selection` will not show "deinstall" entry.

Look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/166254/61218) for the exact procedure to do this

#### 2. You can actually do the selected task, i.e deinstall them

It is not recommended, If you have done a `dpkg --clear-selections` accidentally, which mark all packages as "deinstall" except the essentials one *(Here, essentials doesn't mean You can have a system without any unnecessary software, essentials mean, You can only boot and have a very low-level linux system)*.

The command to do the desired task selected is:

```
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

Hope this will answer your query.

---

For more information you can check these links.

- [Ubuntu manual page for dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dpkg.1.html)
- [What do the various dpkg flags like mean?](https://askubuntu.com/a/18807/61218)

Comment: You write "is selected for de-installation or removal (i.e. we want to remove all files, except configuration files)". Well, how did I ("we") select that? Is that what happens when I "apt-get remove ..."? And if so, why are they only "selected for de-installation", why are they not removed instantly when running "apt-get remove"?

Comment: You write that it is not recommended to dselect-upgrade. Is that only because, in the case that one has accidentally run --clear-selections, it goes to bare-bone. Or is it for other reasons as well? It seems sort of like an obvious thing to do, to de-install things that are selected for deinstallation :/ ??

Comment: I can't understand the answer either. I am reading the manual, but it's not clear either. For example,  the package selection state "install" is described as "The package is selected for installation.". But I find the packages marked as 'install' have all  already been installed in my system. What does it mean 'selected for installation'? (when it's already installed?)

Comment: @MadsSkjern I observe that `apt remove` does mark certain packages as `deinstall` in Ubuntu 19.10. I have no idea why it doesn't just remove it immediately. Full example at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54239534/895245

Answer (score 17):

The "sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade" answer did not work for me. To remove a single deinstalled package I used:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove <package_name>
```

Answer (score 17):

If `apt-get --purge` fails to remove the package try the following:

Check the de-installed packages to make sure you really want to remove them.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f1
```

If you are sure, execute `dpkg --purge`:

```
sudo dpkg --purge `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | cut -f1`
```

Comment: Note that this will include any package with "deinstall" in the name. Try `dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2 == "deinstall" {print $1}'`

Comment: ... or `dpkg --get-selections | awk '$2 == "deinstall" {print $1}' | xargs dpkg --purge`

Comment: Or just anchor the pattern `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall$ | cut -f1 | xargs dpkg --purge`