# How to set the package selection  status to the current status?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I have made a `dpkg --clear-selections` command and found that all my packages are selected for removal. As [the man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/dpkg.1.html) is saying

> --clear-selections : Set the requested  state of every  non-essential  package to deinstall.

and I later knew, If I do a `sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade` all packages will be removed.

I checked [this question in Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/18807/61218), and read the meaning of each various flags in `dpkg -l` command. There says, The first column shows "desired package state" or selection state and second column shows "current state".

Since, I have no dependency problem now, I want to set my *selection state* as the *desired state* in dpkg database. How can I do this?

I haven't given the output of `dpkg -l` because of large output. The output is all `ri` columns.

Also when I did the command `sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade`, it gave me this message,

```
......... After a long list of package names to be removed...
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  apt ubuntu-keyring (due to apt) libapt-pkg4.12 (due to apt) libstdc++6 (due
  to apt) gnupg (due to apt) base-files bash
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1764 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,359 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,078 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?]
```

Is there any way to reset the packages selection state to the current installed state?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this command to change package status -

```
echo "<package-name> <status>" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Say you have set status of package `zip` to `deinstall`. To rollback to original status `install` run this command-

```
echo "zip install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

To change more packages at once use this command

```
dpkg --get-selections | sed -n 's/\<<current-status>$/<status>/p' | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

for example, to change all packages with status deinstall to install use -

```
dpkg --get-selections | sed -n 's/\<deinstall$/install/p' | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: +1 for your answer. Though your answer is helpful, it will be more helpful, if you can provide a method to change all the packages. I'll try to use this method to generate a script.

Comment: It is dangerous to grep or sed for current status, because the package name could contain such string, too.

Comment: @jarno Adding a dollar sign to the end of the regular expression in `grep` and `sed` makes it safe, because then it matches only at the end of the line.

Comment: @Fritz not quite safe; also beginning of word should be checked. Otherwise by install$ you find deinstall$, too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just needed to do this. Thanks @sarowar for the command.
Steps to script doing this for all installed packages:

```
export IFS='
'
for i in $(dpkg -l |egrep '^[a-z]i.*' |awk '{print $2" install"}') ; do echo $i|dpkg --set-selections  ; done
unset IFS
```