How to get package version in one command line in bash
I'm trying to get the installed version of systemd in the following command, but it returns all lines contain the keyword "systemd".
# dpkg -l | grep " systemd "

ii  gnome-logs                                       42.0-1                                                           amd64        viewer for the systemd journal
ii  libsystemd0:amd64                                249.11-0ubuntu3.12                                               amd64        systemd utility library
ii  systemd                                          249.11-0ubuntu3.12                                               amd64        system and service manager
ii  systemd-container                                249.11-0ubuntu3.12                                               amd64        systemd container/nspawn tools

How to make it return only the following line:
# dpkg -l | grep "__the_rule_for_systemd_"

ii  systemd                                          249.11-0ubuntu3.12                                               amd64        system and service manager

And then, I can use awk to get the version:
# dpkg -l | grep "__the_rule_for_systemd_" | awk '{print $3}'

Here is the expected output:
249.11-0ubuntu3.12

How to write the "__the_rule_for_systemd_" for grep or is there any other command can get the installed version of systemd?
Note:
# package_name="systemd"
# dpkg -l | grep " $package_name "

The "__the_rule_for_systemd_" should also work on other packages, it should be able to get any package by that rule, not just only for "systemd".

dpkg - l is a shortcut for dpkg-query - so just use that directly: dpkg-query --show --showformat '${Version}' systemd

The dpkg-query --show --showformat '${Version}' systemd works, but I want to confirm if this command also works on the packages with "deinstall" status. Do you know how to make a package become the "deinstall" status for testing? See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/165951/dpkg-get-selections-shows-packages-marked-deinstall

If it shows up in the output of dpkg -l, it will show up in the output of dpkg-query. As I said, the former is just an alias for the latter

This should do it:
apt-cache policy systemd | grep Installed

If you only want to return the version number (for a script), search and cut the string with awk:
apt-cache policy systemd | awk '/Installed/ {print $2}'

