# dpkg lists uninstalled kernels

Tags: kernel, dpkg

I have run the following command to remove old kernels:

```
dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

and only the current kernel is now installed, which I have confirmed in synaptic and by checking my boot partition.  However, when I run:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

I get the following response:

```
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-30-generic                         3.13.0-30.55                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic                         3.13.0-32.57                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-34-generic                         3.13.0-34.60                                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-30-generic                   3.13.0-30.55                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic                   3.13.0-32.57                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-34-generic                   3.13.0-34.60                                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.34.40                                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Probably not a problem, but just wondering why versions -30 and -32 are reported as present?

Comment: See [What do the various dpkg flags like 'ii' 'rc' mean?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean)

Comment: I wonder why purge does not remove config files.  -33 seems to have been fully purged.

Comment: Have you rebooted since running the purge command? I think sometimes the config files don't get cleaned up until reboot

Comment: A few times, but still lingering.  It occurs to me that I installed network card driver modules for the first two kernels I ran.  Haven't needed them since  the third iteration.  I wonder if that's the configuration that remains...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is indeed in the first two letters of the line.  The first column is a desired state and the second column is a current state.  Relevant to this list is:

```
i = installed
r = remove(d)
c = config files
```

Thanks to steeldriver for directing my attention.