# How to remove "dpkg -l" line with "in" for unwanted i386 package on amd64 system?

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, dpkg

I will really appreciate your help with this.

When I run `dpkg -l bash`, I get this:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                   Version          Architecture     Description
+++-======================-================-================-=================================================
in  bash                   <none>           i386             (no description available)
ii  bash                   4.3-7ubuntu1.4   amd64            GNU Bourne Again SHell
```

When I now do `bash --version`, I get this:

```
GNU bash, version 4.2.0(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law
```

I would like to remove this entry:

```
in  bash                   <none>           i386             (no description available)
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: It's marked as not installed anyway, but try `sudo apt-get purge bash:i386`.

Answer (score 0):

#### What the Current State Is

Lines starting with `in` in the output of `dpkg -l` [mean that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean/18807#18807) a package is set to be installed, but not actually (yet) installed.

Assuming you're not installing the package right now, a command to uninstall it should set it to be uninstalled, preventing its installation and removing that line from the output of `dpkg -l bash`.

#### How to Fix It

One way to do that is to run: `sudo apt-get remove bash:i386`

But please *make sure not to leave out the `:i386`.* That identifies the package for removal as the 32-bit version of bash, which is the one you're saying you don't want and which is the one you probably don't need. You definitely do need `bash` for your architecture (amd64)--even if all users use a different interactive shell, many other packages in Ubuntu depend on it.

#### More details about the current situation, and the "remove" action:

The leading `i` [means](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean) it's marked *to be installed*, so it does make sense to want to clear that line in the output of `dpkg -l`.

The `purge` action (as [fkraiem suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/531537/bash-shell-issue/531549#comment726138_531537)) should work fine too, though it's probably unnecessary (compared to `remove`). Purging a package consists of removal and also deletion of systemwide configuration files. The second letter for the package, in the output of `dpkg -l`, should be a `c` instead of an `n` if systemwide configuration files for the package existed.