# How to remove the MySQL Server 5.5 from Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, package-management, mysql

I wanted to upgrade my MySQL server and client from `v5.5.49` to the latest `v5.6.*`. To do this I firstly tried to uninstall the old version:

```
$ apt-get remove mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
```

I didn't use the `--purge` argument, in order to keep the current settings.

But it the `mysql-server-5.5` could not be uninstalled:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
libdbd-mysql-perl               install
libmysqlclient18:amd64          install
mysql-common                    install
mysql-server-5.5                deinstall
php7.0-mysql                    install
```

However, I installed then the new version:

```
$ apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 mysql-client-core-5.6
$ apt-get install mysql-server-5.6 mysql-server-core-5.6
```

Now two MySQL Server versions are installed:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
libdbd-mysql-perl               install
libmysqlclient18:amd64          install
mysql-client-5.6                install
mysql-client-core-5.6           install
mysql-common                    install
mysql-server-5.5                deinstall
mysql-server-5.6                install
mysql-server-core-5.6           install
php7.0-mysql                    install
```

But the newer one is in usage:

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-------------------------+
| VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Anyway though the upgrade itself was successful I would like to get my system clean again and uninstall the old version.

**How to uninstall the old MySQL Server version (without to remove the configs)? Is it possible to do this over an `apt` package manager (`apt-get`/`aptitude`)?**

---

**UPDATE**

Answering fkraiem's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777741/how-to-remove-the-mysql-server-5-5-from-ubuntu-14-04?noredirect=1#comment1162910_777741):

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mysql
ii  libdbd-mysql-perl                         4.025-1                                             amd64        Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libmysqlclient18:amd64                    5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        MySQL database client library
ii  mysql-client-5.6                          5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-client-core-5.6                     5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        MySQL database core client binaries
ii  mysql-common                              5.7.12-1~exp1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1                 all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
rc  mysql-server-5.5                          5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-5.6                          5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-5.6                     5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1                             amd64        MySQL database server binaries
ii  php7.0-mysql                              7.0.3-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1                       amd64        MySQL module for PHP
```

Comment: `dpkg --get-selections` is weird, can you post the output of `dpkg -l | grep mysql` as well?

Comment: OK, now I see: `rc  mysql-server-5.5` means "[only the config files are installed](http://askubuntu.com/a/18807/176996)". Thank you for the valuable hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rc  mysql-server-5.5` means, that the package is uninstalled (`r`), but some configuration files remain (`c`) (in case you want to install it again later). In order to remove them (and make the package disappear from `dpkg -l` altogether), use `sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.5`.