# Quick check to find if ogre is installed and then uninstall if required

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, software-uninstall

How can one do a quick check to find if ogre is installed? For example querying the current version of ogre like OpenSceneGraph allows `osgversion`. A command will be preferred like this. Solution for Ubuntu will be preferred but Windows will also be good to know.

I am interested in finding all versions of ogre on my computer and remove only the versions that i don't want. What is the exact command to remove ogre? Something like:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge <something>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with `ogre` but there is a simple test to see if any `ogre` packages are installed:

```
andrew@athens:~$ sudo dpkg -l *ogre*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                        Version            Architecture       Description
+++-===========================-==================-==================-===========================================================
un  libogre-1.8.0               <none>             <none>             (no description available)
un  libogre-1.9.0               <none>             <none>             (no description available)
ii  libogre-1.9.0v5:amd64       1.9.0+dfsg1-7      amd64              3D Object-Oriented Graphics Rendering Engine (libraries)
```

This indicates the name of the `ogre` package and also gives the version number that you are after. You can see that I have installed: `libogre-1.9.0v5`, there is a nice explanation of these codes [here...](https://askubuntu.com/q/18804/57576) but suffice it to say that that it demonstrates versions 1.8.0 and 1.9.0 *not installed* while 1.9.0v5 *is installed*.

To remove this package is then a simple process of running:

```
sudo apt-get remove libogre-1.9.0v5
```

And this will safely remove your `ogre` package...