# System Settings (unity-control-center) does not open

Tags: 16.04, system

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.

My system settings do not open but only flash a very fast 3 times. It did open a few times but not any more.

In the terminal I typed

```
unity-control-center
```

and got

```
** (unity-control-center:10490): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
(unity-control-center:10490): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Then I tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-control-center && sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-control-center
```

Also tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

No change at all.

Comment: are you using wayland?

Comment: In my case going to settings didn't do anything, somehow/something remove `unity-control-center` package (was in [**rc** state](https://askubuntu.com/a/18807/349837)). I installed and everything went fine.