# Why does "apt list --all-versions" show more packages than "dpkg -l"?

Tags: apt, dpkg

According to `man apt`,

```
list (work-in-progress)
   list is somewhat similar to dpkg-query --list in that it can display a 
   list of packages satisfying certain criteria. It supports glob(7) 
   patterns for matching package names as well as options to list 
   installed (--installed), upgradeable (--upgradeable) or all
   available (--all-versions) versions.
```

But, in at least two cases, `hunspell` (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1036619/248158 for the output) and `libreoffice`, the `apt list --all-versions` list is far longer:

```
apt list --all-versions | grep -E "^hunspell"
apt list --all-versions | grep -E "^libreoffice"
```

result in far more hits than

```
dpkg -l hunspell*
dpkg -l libreoffice*
```

(`dpkg-query --list` gives the same output as `dpkg -l`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dpkg` can only provide information about what it knows, which is limited to packages and versions that had some `dpkg` operation applied to them.

`apt`, on the other hand, has far more information - it includes everything in the package lists it gets from repositories. Obviously it's unlikely that `dpkg` operations have been done for most available packages and versions, and so of course the output of `dpkg-query` does not include those and is, hence, limited.