# Your python3 install is corrupted Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink

Tags: 18.04, apt, upgrade, python3

I am trying to update from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, but when I run `do-release-update`, I get error:

```
su@sudo:~$ do-release-upgrade -d 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [1,554 B]                                         
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,342 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,343 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'focal.tar.gz' against 'focal.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'focal.tar.gz'
Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' 
symlink.
```

ls -al /usr/bin | grep python3

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          29 Mar 27  2018 dh_python3 -> ../share/dh-python/dh_python3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          23 Apr 18 07:26 pdb3.6 -> ../lib/python3.6/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          23 Nov  7  2019 pdb3.7 -> ../lib/python3.7/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          31 Oct 25  2018 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          19 Jun 10 15:12 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          16 Jun 10 14:36 python3.6 -> /usr/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          33 Apr 18 07:26 python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     4526456 Apr 18 07:26 python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          34 Apr 18 07:26 python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4873376 Nov  7  2019 python3.7
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4873376 Nov  7  2019 python3.7m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          16 Oct 25  2018 python3-config -> python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          10 Oct 25  2018 python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          17 Oct 25  2018 python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          34 Apr 18 07:26 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root        3283 Apr 18 07:26 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          33 Oct 25  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          34 Oct 25  2018 x86_64-linux-gnu-python3m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
```

$ dpkg -l | egrep  -v '^ii|rc'

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=============================================-===================================================-============-=================================================================================
rFR python3                                       3.6.7-1~18.04                                       amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
```

Comment: The release 19.04 is no longer supported. If your current version is 18.04, you should directly upgrade to 20.04. But first, run the following commands: `apt autoclean && apt autoremove && apt update && apt dist-upgrade` on your 18.04 version. These commands should not return any errors.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I tried it but it is giving error
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

Comment: 19.04 is not Eoan. Eoan is 19.10. The upgrade path 18.04->19.10 isn't supported. Even if you fix Python 3 issues, you'll get stuck on `Upgrade Path not supported error`. What is the output of `type -a python3`?

Comment: @Kulfy I tried it gives python3 is /usr/bin/python3

Comment: And what about `file /usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: @Kulfy It gives  /usr/bin/python3: symbolic link to /usr/bin/python3.6m

Comment: @Kulfy I tried that before but it still didnt work

Comment: What exactly did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: `ls -al /usr/bin | grep python3` please add outputs from commands to your question.

Comment: @Kulfy I tired what Daniel K's solution but it didnt work

Comment: @nobody added please check

Comment: Daniel K's answer is about symlink of Python 2. You should fix symlink for Python3. `python3` should point to `/usr/bin/python3.6m`. Did you changed symlinks in the past?

Comment: @Kulfy my python3 is pointing to /usr/bin/python3.6m but still i am getting that error

Comment: sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3. This fix worked for me. Prior to this fix, I had  /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
and /etc/alternatives/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.6.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3
```

package was in unclean state

```
rFR python3
```

[what it means](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean)

The next would be to upgrade to ubuntu 20.04. Make sure that in file

/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades

```
Prompt=lts
```

is set. Make backup from your data and try again.

Comment: I tried this but i am getting /usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: python3 is broken or not fully installed

Comment: Please add to your question `dpkg -l | egrep  -v '^ii|rc'`

Comment: Added please check

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall python3`    If not working show  `uname -a`

Comment: It worked now should i sudo dpkg-reconfigure python3?

Comment: No not longer required. I remove this part from my answer.

Comment: Hey i did do-update-release and i am still getting that error i updated in my question

Comment: Maybe a mod is so kind to open a chat for us,

Comment: True...........

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109168/discussion-on-answer-by-nobody-your-python3-install-is-corrupted-please-fix-the).

Comment: @Kushal and nobody, you can use the chat room now :)