# Can not uninstall codeblocks apk

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, uninstall, code-blocks

I tried to uninstall codeblocks from ubuntu software. After clicking `remove` it's showing "Unable to remove code::blocks IDE. No packages to remove"

I tried another way, by running `sudo apt-get purge codeblocks`  in terminal. But it's showing

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks-contrib : Depends: libboost-system1.62.0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libhunspell-1.4-0 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwxsmithlib0 (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is to be installed
                      Depends: codeblocks (= 20.03) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: valgrind but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cppcheck but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cscope but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cccc but it is not going to be installed
 codeblocks-dev : Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is to be installed
 codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.2+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How to uninstall codeblocks?

---

after running `dpkg -l | grep codeblocks`

```
iU  codeblocks                                 20.03-3                               amd64        Code::Blocks integrated development environment (IDE)
iU  codeblocks-common                          20.03-3                               all          common files for Code::Blocks IDE
iU  codeblocks-contrib                         20.03                                 amd64        contrib plugins for Code::Blocks IDE
ii  codeblocks-contrib-common                  20.03                                 all          common files for the contrib plugins for Code::Blocks IDE
iU  codeblocks-dev                             20.03                                 amd64        Code::Blocks development libraries (SDK)
ii  codeblocks-headers                         20.03                                 all          Code::Blocks development headers (SDK)
iU  codeblocks-libwxcontrib0                   20.03                                 amd64        Code::Blocks shared libraries for wxContribItems
iU  codeblocks-libwxcontrib0-dbgsym            20.03                                 amd64        Debug symbols for codeblocks-libwxcontrib0
iU  codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev                   20.03                                 amd64        Code::Blocks development libraries for wxContribItems
iU  codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers               20.03                                 all          Code::Blocks development headers for wxContribItems
iU  libcodeblocks0                             20.03-3                               amd64        Code::Blocks shared library
```

Comment: Ubuntu release/version? Have you tried what the error message suggests already? Results? And did you add any PPA before this?

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install` I tried this method. Did not work. + what does PPA mean?

Comment: @ChanganAuto ........

Comment: PPA = 3rd party repository.

Comment: I downloaded from codeblocks official website. .deb package

Comment: Again, Ubuntu release/version?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS @ChanganAuto

Comment: This likely doesn't relate to your issue, but if you're using 20.04.1 then you are months behind on upgrades/security-fixes, as https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/ shows the release of 20.04.2, and the date refers to the ISO release date as installed systems upgraded to it before the listed date on the annoucement.  I'd suggest upgrading (or at least checking, you may find you're actually already running 20.04.2, or you've had this issue for months!)

Comment: It looks like it's not fully installed. What does `dpkg -l | grep codeblocks` return?

Comment: @mchid I will add it to the ques

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The packages available for download are the Debian version. These are incompatible on Ubuntu because of conflicting files. Codeblocks is available from the default Universe repository on Ubuntu (version 20.03-3). Also, the Ubuntu packages were consolidated into a handful of packages so there's no need to download anything extra.

**First**, uninstall the debian codeblocks packages using the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep codeblocks | awk '{print $2}') libwxsmithlib0 libwxsmithlib0-dev wxsmith-dev wxsmith-headers
```

**Then**, run the following commands to update your package list and reinstall codeblocks from the Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall $(apt-cache search codeblocks | awk '{print $1}')
```

---

To explain the commands used, the following command searches for and lists packages related to codeblocks:

```
apt-cache search codeblocks
```

The first column (on the left) lists the package names. So, to list only the package names, we can use `awk` to print only the first column which is represented by `$1` like this:

```
apt-cache search codeblocks | awk '{print $1}'
```

To insert the output of that command into another command, we can use `$()`. So to install the packages listed by the command above, we can use the following command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall $(apt-cache search codeblocks | awk '{print $1}')
```

---

Additional help:

**To search for available packages**, you can use `apt-cache search` like this:

```
apt-cache search codeblocks
```

**To filter the results** to only include results that contain the word "codeblocks", we can use the `grep` command like this:

```
apt-cache search codeblocks | grep -i codeblocks
```

**For more information** about a specific package, we can use the `apt-cache show` command like this:

```
apt-cache show codeblocks
```

**To list all installed packages,** we can use `dpkg -l` and filter the results like this:

```
dpkg -l | grep codeblocks
```

[Click here for more info about dpkg status codes](https://askubuntu.com/a/18807/167115) (e.g., `ii`, `iU`, etc.). Basically, `ii` means fully installed and `iU` means that the package is not fully installed.

Comment: I tried to uninstall using ur cmd. but it's showing `dependency problems prevent removal of codeblocks:
 codeblocks-contrib depends on codeblocks (= 20.03); however:
  Package codeblocks is to be removed.

dpkg: error processing package codeblocks (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 codeblocks
`

Comment: @PronaySarker Okay, I updated the instructions.

Comment: Big thanks for the guide. My Code::Blocks installation was a disaster and you saved the day.  By the way, it's `sudo add-apt-repository universe`.